# Convert existing many to many to reverse many to many relationship using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Could you help me to achieve this XSLT transformation? It's more like reversing relationships...

I have Offers/Offer*/TrimLine*/PRNumber* ---> I want to convert it to PRNumbers/PRNumber*/TrimLine*/Offer*

Input:

```
    <offerStructures>
    <offerStructure>
        <productId>1</productId>
        <brandName>OS</brandName>
        <trimLines>
            <trimLine>
                <productId>12</productId>
                <trimLineName>12TL</trimLineName>
                <prNumbers>
                    <prNumber>
                        <productId>1</productId>
                        <countryCode>IN</countryCode>
                        <brandName>OKI</brandName>
                    </prNumber>
                    <prNumber>
                        <productId>2</productId>
                        <countryCode>US</countryCode>
                        <brandName>LOP</brandName>
                    </prNumber>
                </prNumbers>
            </trimLine>
            <trimLine>
                <productId>13</productId>
                <trimLineName>13TL</trimLineName>
                <prNumbers>
                    <prNumber>
                        <productId>1</productId>
                        <countryCode>IN</countryCode>
                        <brandName>PYU</brandName>
                    </prNumber>
                    <prNumber>
                        <productId>3</productId>
                        <countryCode>AU</countryCode>
                        <brandName>ABC</brandName>
                    </prNumber>
                </prNumbers>
            </trimLine>
        </trimLines>
    </offerStructure>
    ../Multiple Offer Structure
</offerStructures>
```

Required Output:

```
<prNumbers>
    <prNumber>
        <productId>1</productId>
        <countryCode>IN</countryCode>
        <brandName>PYU</brandName>
        <trimLine>
            <productId>13</productId>
            <trimLineName>13TL</trimLineName>
            <offerStructure>
                <productId></productId>
            </offerStructure>
            <offerStructure>
                <productId></productId>
            </offerStructure>
        </trimLine>
        <trimLine>
            <productId>12</productId>
            <trimLineName>12TL</trimLineName>
        </trimLine>
    </prNumber>
    <prNumber>
        <productId>2</productId>
        <countryCode>US</countryCode>
        <brandName>LOP</brandName>
        <trimLine>
            <productId>12</productId>
            <trimLineName>12TL</trimLineName>
            <offerStructure>
                <productId></productId>
            </offerStructure>
        </trimLine>
    </prNumber>
    <prNumber>
        <productId>3</productId>
        <countryCode>AU</countryCode>
        <brandName>ABC</brandName>
        <trimLine>
            <productId>13</productId>
            <trimLineName>13TL</trimLineName>
        </trimLine>
    </prNumber>
</prNumbers>
```

Thanks

Comment: what are your thoughts about that? any particular difficulties? pretty straight task actually..

Comment: i am not much hands on with xslt. I tried but didn't get exact output.It would be great if you can help wit this.

Comment: but why you decided to go with xslt then? =) can you post your version of xslt

Comment: @evilruff It's not all that trivial.

Comment: @DharamThakkar Why dos your output show `<brandName>PYU</brandName>`? There are other brandNames with the same productId (in this example, `OKI`).

Comment: i think the goal is to generate a report of products used per trimline. So I wouldnt call it a reverse honestly.. I agree that generic XSLT can be tricky, but for this example its not really difficult..

Comment: Ya i m using XSLT version 1.0. That's a requiremt :). I was using TIBCO businesworks and to achieve this i will have to write custom xslt only

Comment: ya it's like for each prNumber, to which all trimLines it is associated with & for each trimLine to which all offer it is associated with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not 100% what you need (since you're rather vague with your requirements), but

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="kPrNumber" match="prNumber" use="productId" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <prNumbers>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//prNumber" mode="group" />
    </prNumbers>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="prNumber" mode="group">
    <xsl:variable name="thisGroup" select="key('kPrNumber', productId)" />   

    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($thisGroup[1])">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="productId" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="countryCode" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="brandName" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$thisGroup/ancestor::trimLine" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="trimLine">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="productId" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="trimLineName" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::offerStructure" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="offerStructure">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="productId" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="brandName" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives you

```
<prNumbers>
  <prNumber>
    <productId>1</productId>
    <countryCode>IN</countryCode>
    <brandName>OKI</brandName>
    <trimLine>
      <productId>12</productId>
      <trimLineName>12TL</trimLineName>
      <offerStructure>
        <productId>1</productId>
        <brandName>OS</brandName>
      </offerStructure>
    </trimLine>
    <trimLine>
      <productId>13</productId>
      <trimLineName>13TL</trimLineName>
      <offerStructure>
        <productId>1</productId>
        <brandName>OS</brandName>
      </offerStructure>
    </trimLine>
  </prNumber>
  <prNumber>
    <productId>2</productId>
    <countryCode>US</countryCode>
    <brandName>LOP</brandName>
    <trimLine>
      <productId>12</productId>
      <trimLineName>12TL</trimLineName>
      <offerStructure>
        <productId>1</productId>
        <brandName>OS</brandName>
      </offerStructure>
    </trimLine>
  </prNumber>
  <prNumber>
    <productId>3</productId>
    <countryCode>AU</countryCode>
    <brandName>ABC</brandName>
    <trimLine>
      <productId>13</productId>
      <trimLineName>13TL</trimLineName>
      <offerStructure>
        <productId>1</productId>
        <brandName>OS</brandName>
      </offerStructure>
    </trimLine>
  </prNumber>
</prNumbers>
```

Note that in the first `<prNumber>` it gives you `<brandName>OKI</brandName>`. This is because your input sample has several branNames to choose from for productId 1, which makes things ambiguous.

Comment: ohh ya. I am sorry that was my mistake. Every PRNumber identified by ProductId has similar brandName. Thanks a lot. It helped a lot.